# Are there any alternatives to Media Lovin' Toolkit (MLT)?

Tags: video, video-encoding, video-editing

I'm looking for command-line Linux tools for creating video slideshows from images and video clips. I would also like to implement a variety of transitions and effects. So far, Media Lovin' Toolkit (MLT) seems to be the obvious choice, but are there any viable alternatives?